# Force WWW when URL contains path using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, session, url, redirect

I'm having a problem with my URL and my sessions.
I wish to have ALL website pages be forced to use `www`. As it looks like now, the website looks like this:

`www.example.com` **into** `www.example.com`

`example.com` **into** `www.example.com`

`www.example.com/example/` **into** `www.example.com/example/`

`example.com/example` **into** `example.com/example` (this is what's wrong)

This is what my .htaccess file looks like:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^wewent\.net
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.wewent.net/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Because the URL does not redirect properly I get double up with sessions one for `www` and one for the website without. How can I prevent this the best way?

Comment: Is this everything you have in your .htaccess file? Also, should exampple be example?

Comment: This is everything I have in my .htaccess file, yes :) That's a typo. My mistake

Comment: I see nothing wrong here. Are you sure that you're not using a cached redirect?

Comment: How can I remove the cached redirect if that's the case?

Comment: It depends on the browser, but it should be as easy as just normally clearing your cache. If you don't know how to do that, there are plenty of online references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to look ok but one thing you should do is always put your other rules before the wordpress rules as a habit. When using wordpress it should generally be the last set of rules since it does all the routing. Now for the redirect, you should probably use `302`temporary which will remove any current cache and verify that your redirects are working properly. Then you can change it to 301 for permanent once it's working correctly.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.wewent\.net [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.wewent.net/$1 [L,R=302,NC]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```